# Point on a finite grid graph

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Suppose we are on a finite 2D grid of points from $(-a,-b)$ to $(a,b)$. In the beginning, we are at the point $(0,0)$ inside the grid. How many points are there that have distance $k$ between $(0,0)$?

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking how many vertices have distance exactly $k$ from $(0,0)$?

If so, the answer is $4k$ for any $k$ which is at least one, and less than or equal to $\min\{a,b\}$.

You can check this inductively.

Look at how the vertices at distance 2 in the grid branch out from those at distance 1. 
The three red vertices in quadrant 1 ($x \geq 0$ and $y \geq 0$) are all adjacent to the two blue vertices in quadrant 1. A similar pattern holds in all four quadrants.

[image]

So let our inductive hypothesis be that the number of vertices at distance $k$ from (0,0) in any single quadrant is $k+1$. (This is true for $k=1$, so we have a base case).

Now let's prove it for distance $k+1$.
Let's first assume we are in the first quadrant. Each vertex at distance $k$ (of which there are k+1 by assumption) has exactly 1 neighbour, directly above it, at distance $k+1$. 
But, there is also one extra neighbour. The vertex at distance $k$ on the x-axis has a neighbour at distance $k+1$ directly to the right (see the figure below, the 'extra' neighbour to the right has a little + next to it).
Thus in quadrant 1, there are $k+2$ vertices at distance $k+1$ from (0,0).

This proof works for the other quadrants by 'rotating' the argument, as shown in the figure below. 
This completes the proof by induction that each quadrant contains $k+1$ vertices at distance $k$ from $(0,0)$.

Note that the vertices on the axes get double-counted, as they lie in two quadrants.
We know each quadrant has $k+1$ vertices at distance $k$, and there are 4 quadrants, with 4 vertices double-counted, so the total number of vertices at distance $k$ is
$4(k+1) - 4 = 4k$.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I want to know when we are on the finite grid, like when we're in the middle of the grid graph $P_n \box P_m$. Do we have any ways to find how many points that have distance $k$ from where we are?

Comment: Because of symmetry (everywhere on the inside of the grid looks the same), this answer works anywhere on the grid, except if you are distance less than $k$ from one of the boundaries. 

If you are near the boundaries, that's a lot messier =/

Comment: I just wondering that is there any function that will depend on 3 variables n, m, and k to find the total number of vertices at distance $k$.